# Trying to implement a CSS overflow:hidden analogue in Flutter

Tags: flutter

This is a working flutter app, it illustrates my problem pretty clearly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Overflowing Widget Example'),
        ),
        body: OverflowingWidget(
          k: UniqueKey(),
          l: -100, 
          t: 50, 
          w: 200, 
          h: 40.0, 
          c: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
          x: [ 
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverflowingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key k;
  final double l;
  final double t;
  final double w;
  final double h;
  final Color c;
  final List<Widget> x;

  OverflowingWidget({
    required this.k,
    required this.l,
    required this.t,
    required this.w,
    required this.h,
    required this.c,
    required this.x,
  });

  @override
  _OverflowingWidgetState createState() => _OverflowingWidgetState();
}

class _OverflowingWidgetState extends State<OverflowingWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            key: widget.k,
            left: widget.l,
            top: widget.t,
            child: Container(
              width: widget.w,
              height: widget.h,
              color: widget.c,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: Row(
                  children: widget.x,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Flutter throws me this gem:

```
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 2552 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row Row:file:///**path
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.
```

However I'm achieving exactly what I want visually, I don't want to fit the content of Row within the available space, I overflow the container on purpose and I want it invisible.

How would you address this exception?
Is there another, more flutter friendly way to hide the overflow, that I'm not aware of?
Can I maybe just ignore the error in production, and accept it in debug mode?

I was also thinking about putting an opaque sizedbox on top of the part that I want invisible, but this seems to be an overkill, when I can totally achieve what I want with the above code.

Comment: To reproduce your error on our side, we want a full code and a view of how it looks like, Please add it to the question.

Comment: Ok, I added some more details so it's probably easier to reproduce

Comment: Right value in Positioned can help you? And reduce the left value to -10>.

Comment: Well, a right value can be calculated, but how would this help me? left value was mistyped, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use OverflowBox to achieve the effect you wanted. The key part is to use Alignment.topLeft for the OverFlow box so the content is not centered in the box and specify maxWidth of infinity because you are fine with the content being any size because it will be clipped anyway.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Overflowing Widget Example'),
        ),
        body: OverflowingWidget(
          k: UniqueKey(),
          l: -100,
          t: 50,
          w: 200,
          h: 40.0,
          c: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0),
          x: [
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              width: 150,
              height: 40,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverflowingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key k;
  final double l;
  final double t;
  final double w;
  final double h;
  final Color c;
  final List<Widget> x;

  OverflowingWidget({
    required this.k,
    required this.l,
    required this.t,
    required this.w,
    required this.h,
    required this.c,
    required this.x,
  });

  @override
  _OverflowingWidgetState createState() => _OverflowingWidgetState();
}

class _OverflowingWidgetState extends State<OverflowingWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            key: widget.k,
            left: widget.l,
            top: widget.t,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              width: widget.w,
              height: widget.h,
              color: widget.c,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: OverflowBox(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  maxWidth: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    children: widget.x,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```